# Flask wrapper function handles a error response correctly when wrapped around one route's function but doesnt for another route function

Tags: python, angular, http, flask, wrapper

I have a flask wrapper function that is used to check for JWT's and verify them. When i use it for one route it works correctly but when I use it for my other route it doesn't. When I mean work correctly I mean that it excepts an error and returns the JSON response defined inside the except block and NOT the error itself. I have specified my code below and the `/decode` route works but not `/predict`.

For context I'm using Angular as my front-end and Flask as my backend.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

**wrapper function**

```
def token_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            # Respond to the preflight request
            return '', 200

        token = request.headers.get('token')
        g.normaltoken = token
        print("-----------from wrapper before trying jwt.decode:",token)
        if not token:
            return jsonify('token is missing')
        else:
            try:
                decoded_token = jwt.decode(
                    token, app.secret_key, algorithms=['HS256'])
                
                
                g.token = decoded_token

            except jwt.InvalidSignatureError as e:
                print("------------"+str(e)+"--------------")
                return jsonify({"message": "Invalid signature"}), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 

            except jwt.InvalidAlgorithmError as e:
                print("------------"+str(e)+"--------------")
                return jsonify({"message": "Invalid algorithm"}), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as e:
                print("------------"+str(e)+"--------------")
                return jsonify({"message": "Token expired"}), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

            except jwt.DecodeError as e:
                print("------------"+str(e)+"--------------")
                return jsonify({"message": "Error decoding token"}), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

**route that works correctly**

```
@app.route("/decode",methods = ['GET','POST'])
@token_required
def decode():
    print("---------From decode : g----:",g.normaltoken)

    return jsonify("generic response from decode route")
```

**route where wrapper doesnt work**

```
@app.route("/predict",methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@token_required
def predict():
    **INSERT ML CODE**
    return jsonify(forecast_data), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

I have tried everything I can with chatgpt and since this was a sort of niche problem I didn't find any relevant resources in forums either.